# SSIS dynamic column names mapping

Tags: sql-server, ssis, columnmappings

My main task is to upload multiple files in a table. The source files doesn't contain headers and once I configure it on source editor, the column names both in input and output columns are empty (see picture below)

[image]

The table consists of 16 columns so I had to manually configure it on the output column to properly map it. It wouldn't be much of a problem to me to do it manually if I only need to do it once. The hard part is I need to upload 12 files for a year (monthly data) and 4 years total.

Any help would very much be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Help with what? What is the specific problem you are having here?

Comment: @larnu I needed to manually add the column names on the Output column section. I need to do it for 12 files/year. So if I need to accomplish example for 4 years, then that would be 48 iterations. I would like to ask if there is an easy way for  me to populate that part. In addition, the source files doesn't have headers in it.

Comment: No, there is no magic "Read my mind to know what the column names should be" feature. If your files don't have headers, *you* need to define the names yourself.

Comment: I would suggest not even naming them and using the generic names provided by SSIS. if it is the same structure you should only have to map once and then run these through a foreach (file) loop.

Comment: More advanced but could be used in this situation.  Import into generic staging table first, then do your mapping/work/etc from the staging table to wherever you want and your package wouldnt need to change just the code after.